# How to render a Reanimated Value in Text component?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-reanimated

I'm using a PanGestureHandler and want to log out the Value being tracked.

Using a console.log in the `call` method streams the correct value, but using setState doesn't update correctly.

I've tried using a ref value instead to no avail.

Could someone kindly point me in the right direction?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Text } from 'react-native'
import styled from 'styled-components/native'
import { Path, Svg } from 'react-native-svg'
import A from 'react-native-reanimated'
import { PanGestureHandler, State } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'

const { event, useCode, debug, call, block } = A

const Rotation = function App() {
  const translationX = new A.Value(0)
  const translationY = new A.Value(0)
  const [transX, setTransX] = useState(0)
  const gestureHandler = event([
    {
      nativeEvent: {
        translationX,
        translationY,
      },
    },
  ])

  useCode(
    () => call([translationX], ([translationX]) => setTransX(translationX)),
    [translationX]
  )

  return (
    <PanGestureHandler
      onGestureEvent={gestureHandler}
      onHandlerStateChange={gestureHandler}
    >
      <Wrapper>
        <OutputWrapper>
          <CoordsLabel>{transX}</CoordsLabel>
        </OutputWrapper>
      </Wrapper>
    </PanGestureHandler>
  )
}

const Wrapper = styled(A.View)`
  flex: 1;
  align-self: stretch;
  background-color: red;
`
const OutputWrapper = styled(A.View)`
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: black;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
`
const CoordsLabel = styled(A.Text)`
  color: white;
`

export default Rotation
```

Comment: Do you have some example what you want to do ?

Comment: It's pretty much all there. I want the tranlsationX value of the pan gesture to be updated and rendered in the `CoordsLabel` component whilst panning. Essentially, I want a visual representation of the exact position printed out for users to see.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to persist the values through renders. The issue was that the setState call was causing the Animated Value to reset each time, so it never moved from zero.

Memoizing the value solved the issue:

```
const { translationX, translationY } = useMemo(
  () => ({
    translationX: new A.Value(0),
    translationY: new A.Value(0),
  }),
  []
)
```

**NB** Memoizing with `useMemo` isn't the best way to go, as values aren't guaranteed to persist as expected. Opt for `useMemoOne` or an adaptation of `useRef` when in production.